# Dutch passport for my son

Tags: citizenship, netherlands, south-african-citizens

My father is a Dutch passport holder as are my sister and brother and my sister's two children. Apparently I am too old to get a Dutch passport. I would like to know if my son can get a Dutch passport as his Opa has one.

Comment: This is a complicated issue; take a look at Wikipedia's Dutch Nationality article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_nationality_law#By_descent_or_automatic_acquisition_of_Dutch_nationality To assess your son's eligibility, one would need to know where and when you were born, where and when your son was born, where you and he have lived since your births, whether or not you and he have taken citizenship or secured a passport from another country, and if so, when. That's off the top of my head, I may well have missed a few data points.

Answer (score 1):

David's comment is essentially correct.  Your son cannot get a Dutch passport by virtue of his grandfather's nationality.  But he might be a Dutch citizen if all of the following are true:

1. You were Dutch when you were born.
2. You were Dutch when he was born.
3. You passed Dutch nationality to him at his birth (that is, either he was born after 1985 or, if he was born before 1985, he was born out of wedlock and without any legal father).
4. You did not lose Dutch nationality before he reached his 18th birthday.
5. He has not yet reached his 28th birthday.

I've done this off the top of my head, so I might have a detail or two wrong, and there are some very unlikely exceptions that, if he reaches the last step, might extend the deadline past his 28th birthday.

Comment: Point 1 is really a prerequisite to point 2; it's not strictly necessary by itself.